# convert one line xml into csv

Tags: python, xml, csv, converters

I have xml documents in the format which is given below and I cannot find a successful way to convert this to csv using python. I am using `Spyder IDE` and am an extremely amateur `python-ista`. I managed to use an online converter for one of the files, but the remaining files are too large to upload.
I am looking for the output to be columns of  `rowID, PostID, Score, Text`.

Please could someone assist?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<comments>
  <row Id="1" PostId="1" Score="5" Text="Was there something in particular you didn't understand in the wikipedia article? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_%28physics%29" CreationDate="2010-11-02T19:11:07.043" UserId="42" />
  <row Id="2" PostId="3" Score="1" Text="I thought the wikipedia article here was pretty good, but maybe it only makes sense if you have a little quantum mechanics background: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_physics_and_representation_theory Were you able to get anything out of it?" CreationDate="2010-11-02T19:13:34.870" UserId="42" />
  <row Id="3" PostId="3" Score="0" Text="i mostly thought this was a better place for the question than MO." CreationDate="2010-11-02T19:16:09.873" UserId="40" />
  <row Id="6" PostId="4" Score="11" Text="An accurate answer, but if the poster doesn't understand the actual concept of spin (not to mention group theory), this is all but useless." CreationDate="2010-11-02T19:32:15.410" UserId="13" />
  <row Id="7" PostId="2" Score="2" Text="I'm tempted to answer: with much difficulty, in a highly qualitative way, and only by reading a fair-sized book. There are many decent pop-sci books on string theory; I can't remember the names of any I read, but I'm sure someone can recommend one or two." CreationDate="2010-11-02T19:36:53.290" UserId="13" />
  <row Id="8" PostId="8" Score="0" Text="so the fundamental particle is acting on the quantum states?" CreationDate="2010-11-02T19:36:55.263" UserId="40" />
```

Secondly, if some rows do not have all fields or have extra fields, how can I ignore those and only populate what is there for the fields specified? I am getting the below error message, but do not want the additional 3 columns?

```
  ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 41, saw 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is working for me:

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_file = "c:/temp/test.xml"
csv_file_output = '{}_out.csv'.format(os.path.splitext(xml_file)[0])

tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
xml_root = tree.getroot()

with open(csv_file_output, 'w') as fout:
    fout.write("Id,PostId,Score,Text")
    for row in xml_root.iter("row"):
        id = row.get("Id")
        postId = row.get("PostId")
        score = row.get("Score")
        text = row.get("Text")
        fout.write('\n{0},{1},{2},"{3}"'.format(id, postId, score, text))
```

This could also be done using pandas and saving a Data Frame to CSV but I kept it simple.

A file with the same name but ending in _out.csv will be generated in the same folder as the XML file.